# Can some help me with the Js code - i want to stop the response from API after the 10 input in scroll event. while doing the infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, json, scroll, addeventlistener, infinite-scroll

i was trying infinite scroll using the api Programming Quotes i want to only 10 quotes when i scroll down after the loader but while scrolling down i should get 10 extra instead of that i am getting a bunch of quotes from API. also attaching the github link - https://github.com/Realker23/30JSinfinescroll

```js
const quotes = document.getElementById("quotes");
const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
let page = 1;

const hideLoader = () => {
  loader.classList.remove("show");
};

const showLoader = () => {
  loader.classList.add("show");
};

const getQuotes = async(page) => {
  const quotesUrl = `https://api.javascripttutorial.net/v1/quotes/?page=${page}&limit=10`;
  showLoader();
  const response = await fetch(quotesUrl);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`An error has occured: ${response.status}`);
  }
  const json = await response.json();
  showQuotes(json.data);
  hideLoader();
};

const showQuotes = (array) => {
  array.map((quote) => {
    const quoteElement = document.createElement("blockquote");
    quoteElement.classList.add("quote");
    quoteElement.innerHTML = `<span>${quote.id})</span>
        ${quote.quote}
        <footer>${quote.author}</footer>`;

    quotes.appendChild(quoteElement);
  });
};

const loadQuotes = (page) => {
  showLoader();
  setTimeout(() => {
    getQuotes(page);
  }, 500);
};

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const {
    scrollTop,
    clientHeight,
    scrollHeight
  } = document.documentElement;
  console.log(
    `scrollTop - ${scrollTop}  clientHeight - ${clientHeight}  scrollHeight - ${scrollHeight}`
  );

  if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
    page++;
    console.log(page);
    loadQuotes(page);
  }
});

getQuotes(page);
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h1>Programming Quotes</h1>
  <div id="quotes"></div>
  <div id="loader" class="loader">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the network tab when running your code. The API is only returning 10 quotes per request. The issue is because your scrolling logic is broken so you are sending a lot of additional requests.

Comment: No No i know the api is returning 10 quotes per request and i am unable to think how to fix my scroll logic to return 10 quotes at a time, that's where i need help

Comment: Btw thanks Rory the issue was with my css i fixed it thanks a bunch